# Out of Memory Exception in Matrix RDLC

Tags: asp.net, rdlc

Im working on RDLC report where im using matrix to display the data.

But the problem is when the huge data is loading the report is not opening instead its showing the error `System.Outofmemoryexception.`

The reports without the matrix with huge data is working fine.

The records im trying to load is around 80,000 records.Do anyone faced the same problem?

Comment: Maybe too configuration IIS server, AppPool or web.config issues.

Answer (score 1):

The computer does not have sufficient memory to complete the requested operation when one or more of the following conditions are true:

- A report is too large or too complex.
- The overhead of the other running processes is very high.
- The physical memory of the computer
  is too small.

A report is processed in two stages. The two stages are execution and rendering. This issue can occur during the execution stage or during the rendering stage.

If this issue occurs during the execution stage, this issue most likely occurs because too much memory is consumed by the data that is returned in the query result. Additionally, the following factors affect memory consumption during the execution stage:

- Grouping
- Filtering
- Aggregation
- Sorting
- Custom code

If this issue occurs during the rendering stage, the cause is related to what information the report displays and how the report displays the information.

Solution:

1. configure SQL Server to use more than 2 GB of physical memory
2. Schedule reports to run at off-hours when memory constraints are lower.
3. Adjust the MemoryLimit setting accordingly.
4. Upgrade to a 64-bit version of Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services.
5. Redesign Report like
   Return less data in the report queries.
   Use a better restriction on the WHERE clause of the report queries.
   Move complex aggregations to the data source.
6. Export the report to a different format. You can reduce memory consumption by using a different format to display the report like Excel, PDF etc
7. Simplify report design like Include fewer data regions or controls in the report or   use a drillthrough report to display details.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it is not problem of how big is dataset (how many rows), it is question of matrix report design. If variable in columns part of matrix has big value domain (more then 300 lets say) and you already have a variable with big value domain in rows part of matrix. It is not problem when both variable with big value domain are in rows or columns part of matrix. So different design, or create dataset   which depend of value domain of variables with big value domain.

Comment: You might want to elaborate, e.g. on which solution you imply by this observation.

Comment: I cannot decipher that, but if you think it explains your solution please [edit] it into the post, so that it is more according to [answer].

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).